# Android Studio: Minimum API Level Selection

Tags: android, api, mobile, android-nougat, android-emulator

I am here to ask what minimum API level in Android Studio should I pick in order to allow my app to support most of the android devices?

And what is the best targetSdkVersion?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards) to see what the  API install percentage is, it get updated regularly.

As for the target API, it's always best to target the latest.